# Android custom resolution 1920x1200

Tags: android, screen, resolution

I'm building an Android app for Asus Transformer Infinity Pad.
**I do not work with the Emulator**, but directly with the tablet.
I was working with the maximal possible resolution of 1280x800 (which I've selected from the editor menu) and it looks good both in Eclipse graphical editor and on the tablet itself.

Apparently, I've found that tablet's resolution is HD 1920x1200. As I want to get most of the tablet's resolution, I'd like to work with 1920x1200 both in editor and on tablet.

**1. How do I set up a custom resolution of 1920x1200 in Eclipse Graphic Editor (not emulator)?**
**2. How do I tell the tablet itself to work with 1920x1200 resolution?**

Thanks

=====================
*OS: Android 4.2.2

SDK: API 17

Tablet: Asus Transformer Infinity Pad TF700T*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Short answer: everything's fine, don't worry about it.

The tablet will pretty much always use the default/native/max resolution. If everything looks good, then don't worry about it. It *is* using the full resolution anyway. You can't change the graphical layout editor to use custom resolutions as far as I know, so you don't have much choice there (at least for now). It sounds like working with the 1280x800 config gets you close enough that it looks good both in the editor and on the device, so really you don't need to change anything, and there'd be little benefit anyway unless you have some really complex layouts that simply don't fit into the smaller resolution screen (which again, would only be in the editor, the device would use the full resolution).

Comment: I got a graphical design from my designer. This design was planned for 1920x1200. I need to place all the elements with sizes according to the design. So I simply cannot fit all the components if I have less space. Thanks

Comment: Not that I recommend setting all positions/sizes by pixel, but that just means you'll have to use the text editor instead of purely the graphical editor.

Comment: I've tried in text editor, but stuff doesn't fit on the screen when I run it on the device. The device thinks I work with 1200x800 :(

Comment: You may want to post a different question with your specific layout to resolve those issues, but the device doesn't assume a different resolution. That's just not how it works. If you're doing pixel-precise layouts then make sure you're using px and not dp. This will severely limit portability to any other device though.

Comment: I feel this is very close to what I need (as I have a single my own device). The problem is that I cannot set size to 50px for example. The only options I see are 50dp, fill_parent, match_parent, and wrap_content. The editor doesn't accept anything else.

Comment: Again, use the text editor. It probably doesn't accept px values because that's generally not recommended. It makes your layouts very brittle and non-portable.

Answer (score 1):

**1. How do I set up a custom resolution of 1900x1200 in Eclipse?**
Possible [Duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5383788/screen-size-in-eclipse-simulator#):

> In Eclipse if you Select the Android SDK and AVD Manager in the Window drop down menu.
>   You should be able to change the screen size of your Android Virtual
>   Device (Emulator) there.

**2. How do I tell the tablet itself to work with 1900x1200 resolution?**
I assume you mean 1920x1200, but I am still not completely sure what you are asking here. The default resolution of the Asus Transformer Infinity Pad TF700T is 1920x1200.

If you did indeed mean 1900x1200, and you want to force the resolution of the TF700T to be 1900x1200 than I am afraid your out of luck. I don't think this is possible, and I don't really see why you want this.

There are a few apps available that can change your screen resolution, if your device is rooted, but I am not sure if the TF700T is supported. Apps such as [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.birdapi.android.dpi&hl=en) one.

Comment: thanks for the answer. 1) I do NOT use Emulator so AVD question didn't help here. 2) You are absolutely right - the resolution is 1920x1200. And I want to use device's native resolution, but maximal possible. I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

1. How do I set up a custom resolution of 1900x1200 in Eclipse?

No need to set any resolution for your eclipse

work with your normal x-large mdpi resolution 
let say

```
 x-large-mdpi 1280 x 800  =1 
 x-large-hdpi 1920 x 1200  =1.5 
 x-large-xdpi 2560 x 1600  =2
```

so when you supply graphics for mdpi,hdpi,xhdpi that will work prefectly.

so let design with your normal resolution in your emulator 1280x800

2 How do I tell the tablet itself to work with 1900x1200 resolution?

Google recently released a Device Availability Dialog in the Developer Console that allows you to select the particular device to install. [link here](https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/1286017?hl=en&ref_topic=2897459)

[How to restrict android app to specific device make?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9510829/1012284)

if you want only for tablet support you can do like this

```
<supports-screens
        android:smallScreens="false"
        android:normalScreens="false"
        android:largeScreens="false"
        android:xlargeScreens="true"
        android:anyDensity="false" />
```

Comment: 1) Sorry, I didn't get you. Let's say I want a button of size 1200x90. It should cover the entire width (in portrait mode). But in my case it does not fit on the editor's screen, as it's 800 only. 2) I don't need Google Play. I build an app for a single my own device. Thank you